# How to set default value for StructType structField in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I defined my field like that

```
val os = structField(self.os, StructType(
      StructField("family", StringType, true) ::
        StructField("major", StringType, true) ::
        StructField("minor", StringType, true) ::
        StructField("patch", StringType, true) ::
        StructField("patch_minor", StringType, true) :: Nil
    ))
```

But my data little bit not consitent.
Some data has 'os' field and some hasn't and some is empty string.

How set default value for that if they empty or hasn't field set all child field to null.
I use when it null set it null value but I wanted to set it like `{family: null, major: null, minor: null, patch: null, patch_minor: null}`.

```
when(imRDD("os").isNull, null).as("os"),
```

It throws error like that

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? It looks like the problem is somewhere else. What `com.mongodb.DBObject` is doing here?

Comment: ok. I use spark-mongo lib too. Please wait a bit.